# Convert Point to ObjectSpace

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, linear-algebra

[image]I Am writing RobotArm example and Now I want my RobotArm to do such thing:
when arm fingers ar near to cube and I press some key I want to check if
there is a collision between those two objects.
The solution is to translate center of the cube to robot finger object space and then calculate distance between sphere and center.
I have

> Matrix4 transform = robotArm.getObjectSpaceTransform();

which returns transform I need to move my center in arm object space:

> glMultMatrixd(transform);
>
> cube.draw();

this will draw cube to correct way.

I tried to multiple cube.center * transform but It's not working..
Is there a way to do it?
Any hint will be helpful..

@Edit:
This link helped me: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/

And The final program: [3D Robot Arm Simulation Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBCVAiKTLiI&feature=share)

Comment: In OpenGL vector transform is reverse : Matrix * vector  see this:http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: Also you should put more code if you want to be helped.

Comment: To be clear, the **white** *sphere* is the reference point you are trying to transform relative to, correct? Your description of *"robot fingers"* adds some confusion, since each one of them also appears to have a **red** *spherical* pivot point.

Comment: @user1268492: If you've answered your own question, please post the answer below or delete the question. Thanks.